# AIR mobile always in landscape

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am making an app in AIR mobile that I need to be in landscape mode all the time. On most devices this is OK, but on some devices (Motorola XOOM for example) the app launches in landscape. At least on the build in emulator that comes with Flash Builder 4.5. I don't know if this is a problem with the emulator or if the XOOM has different orientations than most devices. 
Anyway, I want to make sure that the device is always in landscape mode. This can be checked easily:

```
if(stage.stageWidth<stage.stageHeight){
 //rotate screen;
}
```

What do I need to put in if statement to make sure that it is properly oriented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the *-app.xml file you can define how application should act:

```
<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
<autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even with aspectRatio set to landscape and autoOrients set to false in application.xml, sometimes a device's orientation is incorrectly set during the first frame of a mobile air 3.1 app, so stage.stageWidth will return the smaller of the two dimensions. Several frames later it will flip to the correct orientation. This could be what you witnessed.

So if you need to know the landscape stage dimensions when your app first loads, use:

```
var width :Number = Math.max(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
var height :Number = Math.min(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
```

You should not need to rotate your entire app manually, but here's how:

```
this.rotationX = 90
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take care in locking rotation in your app, if you ever submit to the Apple store you can be denied if the app won't adjust to the device being held upside down. Many devices differ in what their 'default' orientation is, but setting your app descriptor with a starting aspect ratio of landscape should work. In AIR 3.3 there is a change so that setting stage.aspectRatio will keep the expected aspect ratio, regardless of the device's default orientation, or the device being upside down.

You need to set:

```
<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
<autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
```

in your app descriptor.  You also need to set

```
-swf-version=16
```

in your compiler options.  With these setting and AIR 3.3, the app will hold a landscape aspect ratio, regardless if the device is rotated to the 'top' of the device is on the left or the right.  Setting the aspect ratio to portrait will make the device keep portrait aspect ration, even if the device is held upside down.